# passwd does not work after change CRYPT_DEFAULT

Tags: solaris, password, encryption

I want to change algorithm for password encryption in Solaris 10 server. When I change CRYPT_DEFAULT option from __unix __ to 6, I can not change my old password with passwd command and I get following error message:

```
ld.so.1: passwd: fatal: libnspr4.so: open failed: No such file or directory
ld.so.1: passwd: fatal: relocation error: file /usr/lib/libldap.so.5: symbol PR_Initialized: referenced symbol not found
killed
```

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Sorry to ask the obvious - is your account definitely  local to the server? Does pam.conf refer to ldap?

Comment: Yes, it is. What's your mean about pam.conf?

Answer (score 1):

As the error message states, your installation is missing a file (or a whole package). The following lines will sort it out.

```
ls -l /usr/lib/mps/libnspr4.so
grep libnspr4.so /var/sadm/install/contents
pkgchk SUNWpr
```

If `SUNWpr` is not installed, you need to add it with running

```
pkgadd -d . SUNWpr
```

from an installation media directory.

Comment: /usr/lib/mps/libnspr4.so is not exist!!! Do I need to install this library? How?

Comment: Please run the commands I posted and tell what they display.

Comment: output of ls -l is: /usr/lib/mps/libnspr4.so: No such file or directory, second command has not any output and third command has "WARNING: Package <SUNWpr> is installed but empty" output.

Comment: Remove what remains from this package (pkgrm SUNWpr) then reinstall it.